# Reverse Relationships in Django-Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models . Now the Class Track Model has an Album foreignkey.
I want to write a Track Serializer that has Album Name. How can i achieve that?

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'order')
        ordering = ['order']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

I set depth parameter of Track to 1 but that retrieves album name as well as artist.I just want the album name in the Track Serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A Base Serializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)
        exclude = kwargs.pop('exclude', None)
        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(BaseSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
        if exclude:
            # Drop fields that are specified in the `exclude` argument.
            excluded = set(exclude)
            for field_name in excluded:
                try:
                    self.fields.pop(field_name)
                except KeyError:
                    pass
```

I used the above class to explicitly exclude the arguments I did not want,

Credit : [How to exclude parent when serializer is nested when using Django REST Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852555/how-to-exclude-parent-when-serializer-is-nested-when-using-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of solutions. You can use several types of fields e. g. a StringRelatedField or a SerializerMethodField.

Here is an example with a custom related field:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers


class TrackField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.album_name


class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    album = TrackField(queryset=Album.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('album', 'order', 'title', 'duration')
```

This produces:

```py
track = Track.objects.get(...)

TrackSerializer(track).data  # Returns {'album': <name of the album>, ...}
```