# Exclude fields when nesting serializer Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

serializers.py

```
class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    author = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    last_post_user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('locked', 'views', 'post_count', 'last_post_time')


class ChannelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    threads = ThreadSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Channel
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'category', 'threads']


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    channels = ChannelSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'channels']
```

You'll notice I have nested *ChannelSerializer* in *CategorySerializer*, when I visit the endpoint that queries data using *CategorySerializer* I was hoping it would list out only data from *ChannelSerializer* however it lists data from *ThreadSerializer* as well, I'd assume this is expect behavior since *ThreadSerializer* is nested inside *ChannelSerializer*.

Is there some elegant way I can exclude fields when I nest serializers? in this case I'd like to exclude `threads` from appearing when querying data using the *CategorySerializer*

[image]

I tried the answer from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852555/how-to-exclude-parent-when-serializer-is-nested-when-using-django-rest-framework) but can't seem to get it working in my case unfortunately, it ends up listing the threads again, also I'd think there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be that hard to remove the unnecessary fields from `Meta` option?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I could do that but I have a different endpoint that relies on the ChannelSerializer where I'd like the threads field to be included. I guess excluding the field using the Meta option would exclude the field globally.

Comment: Then, use multiple serializers ( and I would do that)

Comment: You could create another version of ChannelSerializer which doesn't include the threads field, and reference that in CategorySerializer.

Comment: Was thinking of using separate serializers but it seemed a bit redundant , guess I'll stick with it when I need field filtration though. Thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

Creating a different serializer and removing the fields you do not want there (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366605/exclude-a-field-from-django-rest-framework-serializer))  is a better option, but here's an alternative:

```py
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    channels = ChannelSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    # Override so we can remove unwatned fields
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        del rep["channels"]["threads"]
        return rep

    ...
```

In this case, the "threads" key won't be in the API's response, but the queries that return threads for each channel will still run (in other words, it works, but is less performant).

Answer (score 0):

I've got a simple snippet for that using Different serializer. You could extend that in case.

**Serializers.py**

```py
class CSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = C
    fields = ('id', 'f1')

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  c = CSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = B
    fields = ('id', 'f1', 'c')

class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  b = BSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = A
    fields = ('id', 'f1', 'b')


# --------------------------------------------------- #
class CustomBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = B
    fields = ('id', 'f1')

class CustomASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  b = CustomBSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = A
    fields = '__all__'

# --------------------------------------------------- #
```

**Views.py**

```py
class AView(generics.ListAPIView):
  """List C objects"""
  queryset = A.objects.all()

  def get_serializer_class(self):
   url = self.request.path
   if url == reverse("test1"):
     return ASerializer
   elif url == reverse("test2"):
    return CustomASerializer
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
  path('test1/', AView.as_view(), name="test1"),
  path('test2/', AView.as_view(), name="test2")
]
```